# Limiting the number of characters in the except

Tags: excerpt

I am trying to post a news blog section on my home page, but I want to limit the text to 100 characters. I am using this code in the `functions.php` file but it is not working.

I want to limit the amount of character from my blog post. I am using this code in the `functions.php` file but it lists a lot of text:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">'
           . __('Read More', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default character length for excerpt is 55.Just use this code instead.For more details refer to codex

```
function new_excerpt_more( $length ) {
    return 100;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_more', 999 );
```